# How to save "game status" in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I'm coding a really simple Risk game, where whenever you click a country, it changes it's color from red to green, yellow, purple and back to white.

You start with an "all-white" map, what I'm trying to make is create different slots that allow me to lets say once I have colored some maps, save the game in that slot and then reload slot number 1 for example and continue where I left. How could I do this for lets say 4 different slots? The world map is an SVG file which I'm changing each region's color by an `event.target.style.fill`.

Take this code:

### HTML

```
    <svg   width="100%" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                viewBox="0 0 701 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 701 300;" xml:space="preserve">
    
      <g onclick="changeColor(event)">
       <path class="st1" d="M308.6,112.3l-0.1,0.2l-0.1,0.2l-0.1-0.1h-0.1l-0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1h0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1L308.6,112.3L308.6,112.3z
            M313.4,111.6v0.2l0.1,0.1l-0.1,0.2v0.1l-0.1,0.1l-0.2,0.1l-0.1,0.1l-0.2-0.1l-0.2-0.2l-0.1-0.1v-0.2l0.2-0.1v-0.2v-0.1h0.2h0.1h0.1
           L313.4,111.6z M309.9,111.8L309.9,111.8l-0.2-0.1l-0.1-0.1v-0.1v-0.1h0.1h0.1l0.2,0.1v0.1L309.9,111.8L309.9,111.8z M312,110.6
           L312,110.6l-0.2,0.2l-0.1,0.2l-0.1,0.1v0.1l-0.1,0.2v0.1l-0.2,0.2v0.1h-0.1l-0.2,0.1l0,0v-0.1l-0.1-0.1v-0.1l-0.1-0.1v-0.1l-0.1-0.2
           l0.2-0.1l0.1,0.1l0.2-0.1h0.1l0.2-0.1l0.2-0.1v-0.1l0.2-0.1h0.2L312,110.6L312,110.6z M315.6,111.6l-0.1,0.1h-0.1h-0.1h-0.1v-0.1
           h0.1l0.2-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1v-0.2V111l0.1-0.2l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.2l0.1-0.3l0.1-0.1h0.1l0.1,0.1v0.2v0.2v0.2v0.2l0,0l-0.1,0.2l-0.1,0.1
           H316L315.6,111.6L315.6,111.6z M308.8,110h0.1l0.1,0.1l0.1,0.2l-0.1,0.1v0.1l-0.2,0.3l0,0v-0.1l-0.1-0.3v-0.1v-0.1L308.8,110h0.1
           H308.8z M317.1,109.3L317.1,109.3l-0.1,0.3l-0.2,0.2h-0.2l-0.1,0.2l-0.2-0.1l0,0l0.1-0.1v-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1h0.1l0.1-0.1h0.2l0,0
           L317.1,109.3l0.1-0.1l0.1,0.1H317.1z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

### JS

```
function changeColor(event) { 
    clicks++

    if (clicks == 1)  {
      event.target.style.fill = "#DA4567";
  }
    if (clicks == 2) {
        event.target.style.fill = "#7aeb34";
   }
    if (clicks == 3) {
        event.target.style.fill = "#ffe70a";
}
    if (clicks == 4) {
        event.target.style.fill = "#ba0afa";
}
    if (clicks == 5) {
        event.target.style.fill = "#FFFFFF";
        clicks = 0;
}
}
```

### CSS (INITIAL COLOR = WHITE)

```
.st1{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-linejoin:round;}
```

Here's the live demo and website so that you can check it out. The last thing I've added is the UI for saving and loading games.(Can be found on the "Load/Save game" button.

https://risk-git-saves-system.swilkery.vercel.app/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use localStorage for saving the state of your app, you want to create functions like the following:

```
function save(slotIndex, clicks) {
  let slots;

  try {
    slots = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('slots'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  if (!slots) {
    slots = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  }

  slots[slotIndex] = clicks;

  localStorage.setItem('slots', JSON.stringify(slots));
}

function restore(slotIndex) {
  let slots = [];

  try {
    slots = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('slots'));
  } catch (e) {
    alert('no slots found in local storage');
  }

  return slots[slotIndex] || 0;
}
```

There's a version of your app with my changes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Richardinho/aqt1koLg/).

One thing to note is that the state that we are saving is only the number of clicks that have occurred, which correspond to the next color that will be used to color in a country.

I suspect that what you really want to save are the colors of the countries themselves.

This would require a somewhat more complicated data structure:

```
const slots = [
  
  {
    currentColorIndex: 2,
    selectedCountries: [
       { id: 'spain', colorIndex: 3 },
       { id: 'usa', colorIndex: 1 },
    ]
  },
  ... other slots
  
];
```

This can also be stored in localStorage as long as it is stringified (all values in localStorage must be strings).
In your app, you would need to update this structure whenever you changed a color in the SVG, making sure they stay in sync with one another.

This is where apps begin to get complicated and I would recommend looking at something like the MVC (Model View Controller) pattern to see how developers typically handle this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and work!!! I'm trying to see your jsfiddle but it is throwing this error on the console when save 1 is clicked: 
<a class='gotoLine' href='#[object Error] { ... }'>[object Error] { ... }</a>
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#1104:16'>1104:16</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setItem' of null" 
Any clue?

Comment: hmm. I'm not getting that. setItem is called on localStorage so it appears that you don't have localStorage within your environment.I've created this in the latest version of Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: This is weird. Im now using Chrome too, error is not showing up, but whenever i click save, reload the page and click load 1, it simply isn't loading. By the way, would this click system work if lets say its not by turns but rather a "I need color green here, so I click twice in that country for that" approach? Another thing, I'm copying both the functions and the save1.addEventListener etc etc to my actual files and something is making the model box not appear when clicked, it seems to be the save1.addEvetns etc causing some trouble I've tried both in Brave and Chrome

Comment: If you open up the dev tools, click on the Application tab and look in the Local Storage section, you should see this being updated whenever you click save.You should see an array of four numbers corresponding to the value of the 'clicks' variable in each slot. When you click load, you'll see that the next time you click a country, the color will correspond to what was in the array.

Comment: There's something going on... cause it's simply not changing anything. I will have to try with another PC. I may have to dig deeper with the more complex solution you provided. It's way out of my knowledge level at the moment. THANK YOU

Comment: I am sorry about that. I promise it does work on mine. In any case, I'd regard it more as a proof of concept than actually working code, but good luck with the game. It certainly looks interesting.